# Understanding crash log "this may be a leak"

Tags: memory-leaks

My app sometimes throws strange log like:

: notify name "com.apple.iapd.notify.extendedMode" has been registered 40 times - this may be a leak
: notify name "com.apple.iapd.notify.extendedMode" has been registered 100 times - this may be a leak
: notify name "com.apple.iTunesStore.daemon.launched" has been registered 1700 times - this may be a leak

and repearts many times.

I could not find out googling that.

Please help.
Thanks!

Kostia.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same message when launching multiple background downloads through newsstand. But it works.